# in network setup super admin has the tinyMCE buttons and the regular admin has not

Tags: editor, tinymce, multisite, network-admin

in mine network setup, the super admin has the ability to see the tinyMCE editing buttons in the option page, but when i switch to a regular adimin, i can see only the HTML editing buttons (the "rich text").
what can be the reason for that?
i can find any thing in the functions.php that indicates that i registered a enqueue script just for super admins...

Comment: even if i set another user to super admin he can't see the rich text. just the first super admin can, and only him.

Comment: o.k. i've made some progress. i found out that the filter `add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_change_mce_buttons');` us acting strangely on users who aren't the superadmin of the network. i don't know if that true also to for standard Wp installations (non-network)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o.k. the problem is based on a conflict in some of the filters of the tinyMCE, maybe only when it's a network setup (i don't know exactly which filters are conflicted) but i managed to solved it by:
1. installing tinyMCE Advanced: i know this plugin isn't supposed to work in the network setup, but hey! it did the trick. some thing in the way its configured ran over the problem of the different editing buttons for different admins that i've mentioned above.

1. and for adding a custom but permanent editing buttons (for all users, without exception) i coded this in my `functions.php`:

   function mce_btns1($orig) {
   return array('bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'bullist', 'justifyleft', 'justifycenter', 'justifyright', 'justifyfull', 'link', 'unlink');
   }
   add_filter( 'mce_buttons_1', 'mce_btns1', 999 );

   function mce_btns2($orig) {
   return array('fontselect', 'fontsizeselect', 'forecolor', 'backcolor');
   }
   add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'mce_btns2', 999 );

   function mce_btns3($orig) {
   return array(null);
   }
   add_filter( 'mce_buttons_3', 'mce_btns3', 999 );

this ran over the default and user-specific configuration of the tinyMCE for all users in the network. that's it.